# Can i use two dataproviders in a single @Test method?

Tags: testng

I have and Excel with data in two sheets(DataPool and Controls).
Both the data have some common values like IDs which is common in both the sheets.
Like for example in first sheet(DataPool) i have 3 columns with values like

ID1,test1,test2

ID2,test2,test3

ID3.........

In another sheet(Controls) i have values like :

ID2,val1

ID4,Val3

In both the sheets there are common values like ID2.

I retrived first sheet values using Dataprovider (DataPool) as Dp1 and second sheet(Controls) as DP2. Now the question is i want to use two sheet values for example whenever i retrive the value of 2nd row from my Dp1 i also want to check 1st row from DP2, as the ids are equal.

How to do this. Help needed please

Can i use two dataproviders in a single @ test method?
If not please suggest some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can combine these two data providers into one and use that one for your test method.

Comment: Thanks for the response Cedric. You mean only one dataprovider which gets the data of two sheets?

Comment: Data providers are just Java methods. Invoke your two existing ones, combine their results and expose these results as a data provider.

Comment: @CedricBeust Would you be kind enough to post an example or may be link to one? Thanks in advance!